# Trigger, initcap a value before a insert (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I know that there is an initcap () function, which will perform a transformation for a 'string'. But I want to know how I can perform a trigger that executes this function before inserting a value in the column name into my table client. In other words how my function 'func ()' needs to be declared.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg
BEFORE INSERT
ON client
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func()

CREATE FUNCTION func()
returns trigger as 
$BODY$

begin
**???**
end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the record before the change that triggered the trigger via the `OLD` pseudo record and after the change via the `NEW` pseudo record in your trigger function. You can also change the latter.

So to change the name of your client use

```
NEW.name := initcap(NEW.name);
RETURN NEW;
```

in your trigger function body.

For more information see [42.9. Trigger Procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).